# Piping input data via a python subprocess

Tags: python

Some preamble:
(Not sure if this is relevant but I am doing all this in Cygwin in Windows). 
I use a program (prog1) that is called with command line options (-R0/10 -I0.5 -Sc ). 
Input to prog1 is a list of (x,y) points. These points can be in a file (let's call it: points.txt) which can be specified on the command line or, as I usually do, via a pipe from some text formatting command (eg. awk) of a raw data file (raw.txt).

So typical use would be (specifying the text file):

```
prog1 points.txt -R0/10 -I0.5 -Sc
```

or (pre-processing the raw data file and piping it):

`awk raw.txt '{print $1, $5}' | prog1 -R0/10 -I0.5 -Sc`

Now I want to do both the above from within python via a subprocess but am having difficulty. I can do the pre-processing in python rather than using the awk function.

I have managed to implement the first case (specifying the file name in the command line) with:

```
args = 'greenspline -R0/10 -I0.5 -Sc points.txt'.split()
p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
print (p.communicate()[0])
```

I can also pipe this file:

```
args1 = 'echo points.txt'.split()
echo = subprocess.Popen(args1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
args2 = 'greenspline -R0/10 -I0.5 -Sc 1D.txt'.split()
p = subprocess.Popen(args2, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=echo.stdin)
print ("4b  ",p.communicate()[0])
```

But I can't work out how to tell python how to pipe the data.

Say I have my data in the form:

```
points = [[x1, y1], [x2,y2], [x3,y3],...]
```

- what is the way to pipe that (in place of the "echo" in the previous example)?

---

Second, simpler question:

If if have my data in the two lists (x) and (y), is there a simple, python way to create my required list of points?

I know I could use:

```
for i in range(len(x)): points.append([x[i],y[i]])
```

but is there a simpler way?

As you can probably gather my programming knowledge level is low so can you please be gentle - and explain all answers in laymans terms!

Comment: See `zip(x,y)` for creating list of tuples based on two independent lists.

Comment: I think your code should read `p = subprocess.Popen(args2, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=echo.stdout)`

Comment: FWIW, the shell `echo` command (in most shells) just prints its argument(s) to stdout, so  `echo points.txt` will simply print the _string_ `points.txt`, it **won't** print the contents of a _file_ named `points.txt`. To print that file's contents in the Bash shell (& I presume Cygwin) you'd use `cat points.txt`. However, running `cat` (or `echo`) via `subprocess` is really not recommended.

Comment: @PM2Ring In  this particular situation the OP is using echo as a variable, don't ask me why!

Comment: @RolfofSaxony: True, but they're also running `echo points.txt` as the command in the subprocess that gets assigned to the `echo` variable.

Comment: @PM2Ring You're absolutely right, well spotted. It's a been over a week since the question and I didn't see the args1 use of it, when I revisited the question today.

Answer (score 0):

Given the x and y coords of the points as two lists `x` and `y` respectively, you can pipe the data in like so (using the optional *input* argument of [`communicate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)):

```
points = zip(x,y)
# convert points to a valid string to pipe in
input = '\n'.join(['{0} {1}'.format(*point) for point in points])

args = 'greenspline -R0/10 -I0.5 -Sc'.split()
p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate(input)
print(out)
```

Comment: Thanks all for those suggestions re zipping however the piping is still not working. @lemonhead when I try your code I get:

    out, err = p.communicate(input)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\subprocess.py", line 819, in communicate
    return self._communicate(input)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1043, in _communicate
    self.stdin.write(input)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Comment: OK - Think I have solved this last one using .encode() on the input. The simple test example I am using had text as input.